# martingale problem: $M_t = f(X_t) - \int_0^t A f(X_s) ds$, $t \geq 0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am considering the Martingale Problem.
Therefore, we consider $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t, P_x)$ as a progessively measurable Markov process with values in $(E, \mathcal{E})$ with associated semigroup $(P_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and generator $A$ on $B(E)$ (the Banach space of all bounded and measurable functions from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$) with domain $D(A)$.

(We defined $D(A) := \{ f \in L : lim_{h \to \infty} \frac{1}{h} [P_h f - f] \text{ exists in } L \}$)

It's about the theorem that for every $f \in D(A)$ :

$M_t = f(X_t) - \int_0^t A f(X_s) ds$, $t \geq 0$
is again an $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$-martingale

My question is why should $M_t$ be integrable and adapted?

I noticed that the Markov process is progessively measurable, but I still can't see why the whole term should be adapted.
I am
struggling to understand the exactly relation to this claim. Tithus.

Comment: Progressive measurability is preserved under Riemann integrals, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626675/36150). This gives that $M$ is progressively measurable and hence adapted. Alternatively you can prove the adaptedness directly using Riemann sums. Since $f$ and $Af$ are assumed to be bounded, integrability shouldn't be much of a problem, right?

Comment: Thanks!! And why is $f(X_t)$ progressive measurable?

Comment: Give it a try... try to prove it on your own. It's really not that difficult. Use that the composition of measurable functions are measurable.